# Converting a string to ints and chars

Tags: java

I don't need an exact solution because this is homework, but I'm having trouble with one thing:

If I have a string consisting of `3 a 2 b 1 c`
I need to get the ints and add them, then get the chars and convert each into a number grade, but I don't know how I can do that. There's no `nextChar()` method right?

Comment: If you want to get character at some position from String then you can use its `charAt(index)` method. You can also get array of characters from your string with little help of `toCharArray()` method.

Comment: If you're guaranteed to have that whitespace between each character, you can also look into String's split() method, which would give you a String array with each character in its own cell.

Comment: If you're asking about `Scanner` not having a `nextChar()` method, you can just use `next()` if there is guaranteed to be whitespace around each grade.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one very simple option.

I'll let you complete how to handle each of the different types.

```
String[] contents = "3 a 2 b 1 c".split(" ");

int i = 0;
for (String c : contents) {
   if (i % 2 == 0) {
      // do something to handle the characters
   }
   else {
      // do something to handle the numbers
   }

   i++;
}
```

Comment: I think he means AAABBC

Answer (score 1):

Is easier in java since char and short numbers means the same, you just need to force the short:

```
int total = 0;
for(char a : "ABCDE".toCharArray()) {
    total += (short)a;
}
```

This will add the ASCII value of the chars, if you have an arbitrary values for your chars then just add a map for conversion:

```
Map<Character, Integer> charValues = new HashMap<>();
charValues.put('A', 5);
charValues.put('B', 7);
charValues.put('C', 15);
int total = 0;
for(char a : "ABCDE".toCharArray()) {
    total += charValues.get(a);
}
```